# setting up the background image of the page outside the <body> tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to setting up the background image of the webpage outside the  tag.. please help me. i have tried searching on google but every demo or example i have seen uses the  tag background image attributes..

is there any other way of doing it besides the  tag like in CSS ?

Comment: By "outside" the body tag - do you mean visually outside of the viewport? the main content area? what exactly? A diagram would help.

Comment: what's wrong with the css? it's what it's used for...

Comment: Why wouldn't `background-image` work for you?

Comment: CSS is fine for me ...but i dont want to use the body background image attributes..

Comment: background-image has only one attibute and it's url to your image, it's not generally background property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

Step 1:

Create a div tag with the id background `<div id="background"></div>`
and place it as the first element in the body.

Step 2:

Put your image tag inside the div tag so now you have `<div id="background"><img src="someimg.jpg" alt="bgimage" />`

Step 3:

In your CSS file add:

```
div#background
{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
 }

 div#background img
 {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }
body,html 
{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: place it a the beggining of the HTML ? means before the head or Body

Comment: @patel.milanb this will pretty much make the background span the whole page if you want.  Like, if it is an image that you do not want repeated or you want 100% of width and height. Like this from my site, [Bullet Videos](http://bulletvideos.com/BulletVideosVScript/siteControls/watch.php?id=109&loc=../uploads/flv/89421926.flv)

Comment: @patel.milanb You're welcome.  You also may want to do additional research to preserve the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 4):

Putting a background anywhere outside of the `body` doesn't really make sense considering the `body` is the viewable, rendered, part of the web page.

To apply a background on the web page, you would indeed use the `body` tag such as:

```
body
{
  background-image:url('..URL HERE..');
}
```

Comment: +1 I think, this is right approach and also most efficient. maybe sometimes can be used background for write less lines if you want to also repeat it or something else :-)